# MongoDB document added but not displaying on website (without a refresh)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple todo list website. So you can create a todo list, and added & delete items from the list. Meaning, there's a `List` collection and an `Item` collection, and where a `List` can have many `Items` inside of it (array of items). I have split my Mongoose (MongoDB) code into a separate file (`model.js`), and my `app.js` file is where all HTTP requests are handled. All Mongoose methods imported into `app.js` are working fine.
The issue is when I add an `Item` to a `List`, by pressing the `+` button on the website, it should show the new item in the list.

[image]

However, after I press the `+` button, the item still doesn't show on the list. It takes for a website refresh in order for it to show. The item does get added to the database successfully, because I can confirm that with a console log and by checking the database itself.

The `+` button triggers the `app.post('/'...` method in `app.js` file, in order to add the item to the list.

My next approach was, to use `Promise` to the `addItemToListInDB` method (in `model.js` file), and using `Async` `Await` this would ensure the item is added to the database before rendering the web page. However, I've got another issue with this approach. Instead of returning the value of the updated list (with the newly added item), I get `[Object Promise]`. And anyway the `Promise` `Async` `Await` still hasn't resolved the original issue. Not sure if a `Promise` is needed in this scenario anyway.

Please refer to my code below (p.s. for the sake of brevity, I've only included the `app.get('/'...` (Home route method) and `app.post('/'...` (adding items method) from `app.js` file. And the adding items method from `model.js`).

Also, apologies in advance for all the console logs, but I was trying to debug the issue. I didn't want to get confused with the Async Await order of execution.

`app.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const date = require(`${__dirname}\\date.js`);
const model = require(`${__dirname}\\model.js`);
const ejs = require('ejs');
const _ = require('lodash');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const defaultListName = "Today's";
  const todayFormatted = date.getDate();
  model.DBUtility.findOneList(defaultListName, (foundList) => {
    if (!foundList) {
      model.DBUtility.createNewListInDB(defaultListName);
      res.redirect('/');
    } else { 
      res.render('list', {
        listTitlePassToH1: foundList.name,
        todayDate: todayFormatted,
        listItems: foundList.items
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const receivedItem = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.listName;
  console.log(`before model.DBUtility.addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList(listName, receivedItem)`);
  const updatedList = model.DBUtility.addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList(listName, receivedItem);
  console.log(`After model.DBUtility.addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList(listName, receivedItem)`);
  console.log(`updatedList: ${updatedList}`);
  if (listName === "Today's") {
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/' + listName);
  } 
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started, listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

`model.js`

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const _ = require("lodash");

//connect to DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>.mongodb.net/database', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });

//create schema
const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String
});

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemsSchema);
const List = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);


class DBUtility {

    // *** DB utility methods

    static addItemToListInDB(listName, itemName) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            List.findOne({name: listName}, (err, foundList) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    foundList.items.push({ name: itemName });
                    foundList.save(err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log(`Item ${itemName} added to list ${foundList.name} successfully.`);
                            resolve(foundList);
                        }
                    });
                }  
            });
        });
    }

    static async addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList(listName, itemName) {
        try {
            const updatedList = await DBUtility.addItemToListInDB(listName, itemName);
            console.log(`inside addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList. updatedList ${updatedList}`);
            return updatedList;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }  
    }
}

exports.DBUtility = DBUtility;
```

Output in Terminal:

```
Server started, listening on port: 3000
before model.DBUtility.addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList(listName, receivedItem) 
After model.DBUtility.addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList(listName, receivedItem) 
updatedList: [object Promise]
Item Cheese added to list Shopping successfully. 
inside addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList. updatedList { 
  _id: 5e9cb7b45ceafe2440e09995,
  name: 'Shopping',
  items: [
    { _id: 5e9cb7c45ceafe2440e09999, name: 'Bread' },
    { _id: 5e9cb7cc5ceafe2440e0999a, name: 'Lemons' },
    { _id: 5e9cb7d25ceafe2440e0999b, name: 'Eggs' },
    { _id: 5e9cb7ea5ceafe2440e0999d, name: 'Butter' },
    { _id: 5e9cbd585ceafe2440e0999e, name: 'Cheese' }
  ],
  __v: 6
}
```

One thing to mention, and I hope this is not a red-herring, when I hosted MongoDB locally on my computer, I didn't recall having this issue. But when I moved to MongoDB Atlas cloud hosting, it seems like the issue started to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why you are having the error:**

You are having this error because in the post request handler, the db operation to update the List collection(`model.DBUtility.addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList()`) is asynchronous i.e it does not complete until some late time in the future, consequently, the redirect response is sent before the update to the List collection completes.

**The Fix:**

To fix this, you need to ensure the redirect response is sent only after the update operation is complete. You can easily do that with `async/await`.
Make the post request handler an `async` function and `await` the db operation to update the list

```
// Note the async keyword used before the request handler function
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const receivedItem = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.listName;
  // The await keyword below ensures the update operation completes
  // before moving to the next statement
  const updatedList = await model.DBUtility.addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList(listName, receivedItem);
  if (listName === "Today's") {
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/' + listName);
  } 
});
```

With this, the redirect response is only going to be sent after the update to the List collection is completed.

One other thing to note is that there is a possibility of the db update operation throwing an error so you might want to consider wrapping the `model.DBUtility.addItemToListAndGetUpdatedList()` method call in a `try/catch` and handle any potential error.

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Thank you :) It make sense as well.  I did think of placing `Async` `Await` where the Mongoose wrapper method was being called inside the HTTP request handler, but just didn't know exactly where to place them. That makes much sense now. Many thanks.